# Convert string to ObjectID in MongoDB

Tags: codeigniter, mongodb

I am developing an API using Codeigniter and MongoDB.
In some parts of the database I have saved the ID of an image in ObjectID format
instead of a string. Now I got an ID in string format and I need to query the database using it.

How can I "convert" a string to an ObjectID so that I can do the query?

From this:

```
34234234234234234234
```

To this:

```
ObjectID("34234234234234234234")
```

Comment: `MongoId` is not a valid type in the Mongo REPL

Answer (score 63):

Using mongoose:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var objectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId('569ed8269353e9f4c51617aa');
```

Using native driver (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21076589/3377073)

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
doc._id = new ObjectId(doc._id); // wrap in ObjectID
```

Comment: `ObjectID` should be `ObjectId` when using native driver.

Comment: Update, we need to add new keyword before creating object.

var objectId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('569ed8269353e9f4c51617aa');

Answer (score 46):

You just need to require the ObjectId function from your mongo.

```
ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

Then you can use it like that:

```
ObjectId("34234234234234234234")
```

Comment: this answer really helped!

Comment: I'm getting: "Error: ReferenceError: require is not defined". What does this mean?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Meteor

```
var id = new Mongo.ObjectID("34234234234234234234");
```

Answer (score 4):

you can now convert string to objectId on mongodb 4.0 and above. there is new feature to convert from string id to objectId

here you can see the documentation [$toObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in an aggregation you can use the following :

```
{
   $toObjectId: <expression>
}
```

Which is a shortcut for :

```
{ $convert: { input: <expression>, to: "objectId" } }
```

From [mongodb documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/)

Answer (score 0):

**or better use**

```
var mongodb = require(‘mongodb’); //this might have been defined at the beginning of your code.
//now use it
query = {_id:mongodb.ObjectId('569ed8269353e9f4c51617aa')};
```

and the rest is the same.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(Extracted from the question)</sup>

---

I found a solution. Just do this:

```
new MongoId('34234234234234234234');
```

Answer (score 0):

**Class constructor ObjectId cannot be invoked without 'new' in mongoose**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var objectId = new mongoose.Types.ObjectId('569ed8269353e9f4c51617aa');
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb'
const query  = {"_id":ObjectId(req.params.productId)}
```

Answer (score -4):

mongo  DB version v3.6.3

how to save string input to MongoDB ObjectId
on express controller code

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId;
user: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.user)
console.log(user, typeof(user))
```