# How to assign an id value in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working with node.js and mongoose. I'm creating a REST API to expose my User model:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
 _id: {type:Number},
 username: {type:String},
 age: {type:Number},
 genre:{type: Number,ref:'Genre'},
 country: {type: Number,ref:'Country'}
});
```

As you can see I decided to include an _id field, so if I want to create a new user I'll need to generate the value for this field, for example:

```
exports.createUser = function(req,res){
 var user = new User({
    _id: //Generate and assing value here
        //Other properties are retrieved from the request object
 });
};
```

How could I "generate" or assign a value to my _id field properly? How does mongo deals with this?

Comment: I'd suggest you let MongoDB set the value for your _id field. If you need an additional identifier field you can go ahead define a different field (say key) and use whatever algorithm you feel like for it (a sequential field or a GUID)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I never used mongoose. but if `_id` is not included in insert query, mongodb driver will generate `_id`s for you as an [ObjectId](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html) object. and if you wish to use your own `_id`s, it's up to you to decide about its type and length, and also *you* have to guarantee its uniqueness among the collection because any attempt to insert a document with a duplicated `_id` will fail.

accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076460/how-to-convert-a-string-to-objectid-in-nodejs-mongodb-native-driver) may be useful, if you are looking for a method for creating custom `_id`s that provides a decent degree of guaranteed uniqueness.

Comment: Ok, so if my POST method doesn't receive the _id param from the incoming request Mongo will generate it for me. Great, this gets rid of my doubt. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

mongoDB requires that _id, if supplied, be unique.  If _id is not supplied, it is created by the client-side driver (i.e. NOT the mongod server!) as a 12-byte BSON ObjectId with the following structure:

```
4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
3-byte machine identifier,
2-byte process id, and
3-byte counter, starting with a random value.
```

more info available here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id