# Select from mongoDB using Mongoose Where ObjectId NOT EQUAL to a particular ID

Tags: regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, objectid

Please how do I go about retrieving records from MongoDB using mongoose where the Model ID doesn't match the given ID. The model is all setup properly. I am not entirely new to Node.js, mongoDB, Mongoose.

I tried using $ne:

```js
var ID = ....

User.find({id: {$ne: ID}},
function(error, users) {
  console.log(users);
  callback(error, count);
});
```

I also tried using RegExp:

```js
var regex = new RegExp('^((?!' + ID + ').)*$', "i");
User.find({id: regex},
function(error, users) {
  console.log(users);
  callback(error, users);
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `_id` instead of `id`?

Comment: What does the document you want to find look like?  JohnnyHK's point about `_id` seems like a good bet, but its hard to help when we can't see what you're searching for.

Comment: @JohnnyHK a string equivalence of _id is exposed as id (virtual field) in mongoose models

Comment: @AaronDufour What am searching for is not really important. Just trying to get all records (documents) not matching the dynamically passed in ID (string)

Comment: @czprobity You can't query against virtual fields like `id`, that's why it needs to be `_id` instead.  But using `$ne` is correct, and `ID` can be a string as Mongoose will cast it to an `ObjectId` for you based on the schema.

Answer (score 7):

As JohnnyHK and Aaron Dufour have commented, you need to use `_id` instead of `id`.

Further, Mongo is expecting an Object and not a String when you query by `_id`.

You can require the native mongodb drivers ObjectID and use it in your code like this:

```
var ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID;

_id = new ObjectID('stringId');

User.find({'_id': {$ne: _id}},
function(error, users) {
  console.log(users);
  callback(error, count);
});
```

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076460/how-to-convert-a-string-to-objectid-in-nodejs-mongodb-native-driver).

Comment: Yeah, thats why i queried by `id` not `_id`. Also i tried this method and it didn't work. It threw an exception when the argument for `new ObjectId` is not a 24 byte hex string, 12 byte binary string or a Number as specified [here](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html)

Comment: This did not work for me too, but the solution by @czprobity worked. $ne worked only with string ID not object id for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks guys, I was finally able to get it working by doing this:

```js
var id = .... (string type)
User.find({_id: {$ne: id}}, 
  function(error, users) {
    console.log(users);
    callback(error, users);
  }
);
```

The string `id`is implicitly cast to `ObjectId` before the comparison. The downside of this is a `CastError` is thrown when the string `id` is not a string representation of an `ObjectId`. The cast will fail.