# How to Convert MongoDB ObjectID String to String

Tags: mongodb, authentication, mern

I'm trying to find the user with the incoming request.

```
router.get("/user", auth, (req, res) => {
    const db = mongoUtil.getDb();
    db.db("mern-auth-2").collection("users").findOne({_id: ObjectId(`${req.user.id}`)})
    .select('-password')
    // console.log(req.user.id)
    .then(user => res.json(user));
});
```

The req.user.id is console logging abcdefg for example and in my database it's ObjectId('abcdefg')

How do I compare these 2? Above is currently what I have coded, which doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string to ObjectId in nodejs mongodb native driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076460/how-to-convert-a-string-to-objectid-in-nodejs-mongodb-native-driver)

Comment: No, I need to extract the value from ObjectId so I can compare it to my incoming request, which just case the number