# Objects with multiple key columns in realm.io

Tags: realm

I am writing an app using the Realm.io database that will pull data from another, server database. The server database has some tables whose primary keys are composed of more than one field. Right now I can't find a way to specify a multiple column key in realm, since the primaryKey() function only returns a String optional.

This one works:
    //index
    override static func primaryKey() ->String?
    {
        return "login"
    }

But what I would need looks like this:

```
//index
override static func primaryKey() ->[String]?
{
    return ["key_column1","key_column2"]
}
```

I can't find anything on the docs on how to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supplying multiple properties as the primary key isn't possible in Realm. At the moment, you can only specify one.

Could you potentially use the information in those two columns to create a single unique value that you could use instead?

Comment: Since I will have many tables, most of them with multiple column keys, this is not practical. It would require a lot of extra logic just to handle the table IDs.

Comment: Accepted as answer since it answers my original question: it can't currently be done.

Answer (score 2):

It's not natively supported but there is a decent workaround. You can add another property that holds the compound key and make that property the primary key.

Check out this conversation on github for more details https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1192

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, conceptually, by using hash method drived from two or more fields.
Let's assume that these two fields 'name' and 'lastname' are used as multiple primary keys. Here is a sample pseudo code:

```
StudentSchema = {    
    name: 'student',
    primaryKey: 'pk',
    properties: {
        pk: 'string',
        name: 'string',
        lastname: 'string',
        schoolno: 'int'
    }
};
...
...
// Create a hash string drived from related fields. Before creating hash combine the fields in order.
myname="Uranus";
mylastname="SUN";
myschoolno=345;
hash_pk = Hash( Concat(myname, mylastname ) ); /* Hash(myname + mylastname) */
// Create a student object
realm.create('student',{pk:hash_pk,name:myname,lastname:mylastname,schoolno: myschoolno});
```

If ObjectId is necessary then goto [Convert string to ObjectID in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825700/convert-string-to-objectid-in-mongodb/34889782)

Answer (score 0):

it's not supported by realm till today,
you can pass your primary keys to the consturcor and mark a field as `@PrimaryKey`, do it this way :

```
public class ProjectsUsers extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String newPrimaryKey;
    private String key1, key2;
    /// other staff
    
    public ProjectsUsers() {

    }

    public ProjectsUsers(String key1, String key2) {
        this.newPrimaryKey = key1 + "|" + key2;
        this.key1 = key1;
        this.key2 = key2;
        /// other staff set
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering here, though it's been a long time since this question. I never did anything serious with Realm. I probably dropped it due to this very limitation.

Comment: ok so it would help someone else.