# failed to $push string like 56aea43cb6be380000616b07 to array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb

The `_id =56aea43cb6be380000616b07;`
I tried to insert a long string like `56aea43cb6be380000616b07` to the `shareids` array in mongodb, it always failed "unexpected token illegal".

I tried this straightforward with the mongo command, it has to be '56aea43cb6be380000616b07' to make it work.

But I checked the type of the `_id` with `typeof` and it is a string. I tried to set it `ObjectID(_id)` but still the same. How could I get this through? Thanks.

```
collection.update({
              "name": name
            }, {
              $push: {
                "shareids": 
                  ObjectID(_id)
              }}, function (err) {
              if (err) {
                console.log("update failed.");
                mongodb.close();
                return callback(err);
              }
```

Comment: How are you defining `_id` as a variable here? Your error message seems to suggest you have emitted the quotes, and in fact it would be another line of code producing the error. Have you even imported `ObjectID` as a function directly?

Comment: yes, I did import ObjectID.

Comment: Hence the error. So you likely need `var ObjectID = require("mongo").ObjectID` to be included in your code to resolve the "unexpected token".

Comment: yes, I did import ObjectID.My point is: how to convert 56aea43cb6be380000616b07 to '56aea43cb6be380000616b07'?

Comment: As I said earlier, it's meant to be a string, so you need the quotes. Anything without the string quotes would be an "unexpected token". Understand now?

Comment: Thanks, Blakes! _id = "'"+_id+"'" should be working for me and was what I after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `"unexpected token illegal"` could be happened with following command.

```
> db.collection.update({name: 'test'}, {$push: {shareids: ObjectId(56aea43cb6be380000616b
07)}})
2016-02-01T11:34:35.738+0800 SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

However, add quotes to this number as bellow, it will be ok.

```
> db.collection.update({name: 'test'}, {$push: {shareids: ObjectId('56aea43cb6be380000616
b07')}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Comment: _id = "'"+_id+"'"; I think this is what I was after:)

Comment: What the type of original `_id`?

Comment: I think this thread is quite similar to what I was after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825700/convert-string-to-objectid-in-mongodb

Comment: still not working: db.collection.update({name: 'test'}, {$push: {shareids: ObjectId('56aea43cb6be380000616
b07')}})  with mongo API. but works with mongo command.

Comment: @ChanAustin, with mongoose API not working?

Comment: solved, I was silly, I closed the db in the code before...