# mongodb query using _id object in lookup localField

Tags: mongodb

we are trying to match _id object to mId foreignfield which is not working.
looking for mondodb docs. they do not have anything on this. Is it possible with mongodb query or not?

_id as object in document

```
   "_id" : ObjectId("56ab6663d69d2d1100c074db"),
```

mId as String in document

```
"mId" : "56ab6663d69d2d1100c074db",
```

query as below:

```
 collection.aggregate([
                {
                  $lookup:
                    {
                      from: "category",
                      localField: "_id",
                      foreignField: "mId",
                      as: "categories"
                    }
               }
            ])
```

**UDPATE**

as a summary, mongodb does not support type coercion in $lookup. so to need above working i have to have _id and mId as **ObjectId** type in documents itself to make it work.

Comment: What is `mId` ? If it is an `ObjectId` as well, it should work fine.

Comment: it is not ObjectId currently. so we need to set foreign keys  as ObjectId itself to make this work?

Comment: It is not required. The `$lookup` operator would work as long as `localField === foreignField`. Note the `strict` equals.

Comment: I assume you want to emulate a JOIN with that aggregation. Please be aware that this aggregation iterates through all your documents and does a query on the other collection for each of the documents. While this may work halfway with only a couple of hundred to thousands of documents, you'll wait minutes when your collection grows larger.

Comment: @BatScream did not get you. so do you mean that _id and mId should be matched only if they are ObjectId type?

Comment: @Markus W Mahlberg i dont have issues as my data is limited

Comment: @jit - They need not be only `objectIds`. For example, It would also have worked if `_id` was a `number` and `mId` was also a `number` and both had the same value.

Comment: You will have issues, since this most likely hides a bad data model. Just you can misuse a feature does not make it a good idea.

Comment: @BatScream so it contradicts to your "It is not required." statement. i need to set mId as ObjectId while saving or any other way to do that?

Comment: @jit - I have updated my previous comment. In your example, since _id is an `ObjectId`, and you are using the field to lookup, the compared field also should be an `objectId`, having the same value.

Comment: @BatScream  Thanks. so we do not have any dynamic typecasting thing here in mongodb?

Comment: @jit- Welcome. There is no type coercion. Please See [this](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#comparison-sort-order).

Answer (score 5):

From Mongodb 4.0 onwards, you can use [$toString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toString/) aggregation operator to convert ObjectId to string.

Jira issue : [Allow $lookup between ObjectId (_id.str) and string](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22781)

---

Now your query should be like below :

```
collection.aggregate([
  { 
    $addFields: { "_id": { "$toString": "$_id" } }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "category",
      localField: "_id",
      foreignField: "mId",
      as: "categories"
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: This worked great thanks. A useful feature to note, the `$addFields` can also work for the `foreignField` value as well - which is what I needed in my case.

Comment: @LukeBrown Can you please elaborate how you did it for the `foreignField`? Since we are running the aggregation on the current collection, it is unclear to me how you could fish for the field to convert to string from the _other_ collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can join id with mid.Though $lookup does not support coercion,use $project pipeline stage and first convert all the mid to Object Id and then try to $lookup

Comment: and how possibly can we do that conversion from string to object id inside aggregation ??

Comment: A bit late to the party but adding this project stage to the aggregation should work: 
{ $project: {
    _id: {$toObjectId: "$_id"}
  }}

Comment: ashe540, there is no "$toObjectId" operator.

Comment: There is no $toObjectId but we can convert to objectId Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825700/convert-string-to-objectid-in-mongodb