# $set is not working on mongodb update

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So im working with `nodeJS` and `mongoDB`. im having a problem with updating a collection and its been a week since im working on it and it really gives me a headache. so this is my Sample collection

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId('51299sdfasdf') //this is just a sample Id     
  "names": [
      "NameA",
      "NameB",
      "NameC"   
   ],
  "names_id": [
     ObjectId('asdfasdf1312'),
     ObjectId('12sda123123a'),
     ObjectId('asdf1212123a')
  ],
  "user_alias": "SampleA"
}
```

then here's my script

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var model = mongoose.model('Sample');

model.update( { _id: req.query._id }, 
       {
          $set: {
             names: namesArray, //this are set of names ex; ['name1', 'name2']
             names_id: namesIdArray //this are set of ids ex: [ ObjectId('sgsdfgsd'), ObjectId('asdfasdfadf')
          },
       },
       function(err, results) {
           if(err) res.status(500).send(err);
               console.log(results);


           }  
       );
```

I know I code it right. in the names_id arrays i specify all the object Ids like this `mongoose.mongo.ObjectId('id here')`. but it doesn't updating anything. here's the result.

```
{ ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 1 }
```

What's the issue here? is this because of the version? my `mongoose` version is `2.15.8`

Please help me out! thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that `req.query._id` is defined? Also, there is no Mongoose version 2.15.8.

Comment: yes its defined. and about the version. when i Type it on my git  npm mongoose -v. 2.15.8. this will show up

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with Mongoose or MongoDB. Can you trying printing the value for `req.query.id`? I think the reason it is not updating it because it does not have record with that specific ID.

Comment: @JoshuaFabillar that's the version of `npm` :D For the Mongoose version, use `npm ls mongoose`.

Comment: @JoshuaFabillar just to be sure: the collection that Mongoose will be using is called `samples`. I mention this because it won't be the first time that people think that the name of the model (`Sample`) is also the name of the collection being used.

Comment: @robertklep. Oh sorry about that. yes this is just a sample :P. @Samay. the req.query._id has a value.`744112df269d36c1c9c69fc`. thats the value of _id.

Comment: alright. so here's the version of my mongoose. `mongoose@4.3.3`. thank you @robertklep

Comment: @JoshuaFabillar `744112df269d36c1c9c69fc` has a length of 23, but a valid `ObjectId` should have length 24.

Comment: @robertklep. hmm interesting. but that Id is generated by Mongodb.

Comment: @JoshuaFabillar are you sure? Because it's not valid.

Comment: @JoshuaFabillar but atleast you can give a try and convert Id(string)  to objectid and check just to give a try

Answer (score 1):

Don't get so frustrate,there is nothing wrong with mongoose,
I think your problem is because req.query.id is a string 
You need to first convert string to ObjectId

Document was not updated because it didn't find any document no other reason just convert _id to object id

Read this to convert I'd to object I'd
[Convert string to ObjectID in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825700/convert-string-to-objectid-in-mongodb)

Comment: Mongoose will automatically cast strings to ObjectId's.

Comment: No it will not cast check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578178/node-js-mongoose-js-string-to-objectid-function

Comment: That question is over 5 years old. Current versions of Mongoose will cast (here's a demo: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/1a227242c78d7415407dfdca3617ab5b)

Comment: But your example they have cast it to string

Comment: The example converts the `ObjectId` to a string, and uses that string as the query input. Mongoose will cast is back to an `ObjectId` automatically. To show that you don't need to convert to `ObjectId` yourself.

Comment: @JoshuaFabillar but atleast you can give a try and convert it and check just to give a try