# Change field type for many documents in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb

I'm learning MongoDb, I have many documents like this in my collection:

[image]

And I want to update my cust_id field from String to ObjectId. I can use Compass to change type but I have very many documents. I've read from Mongo document but still don't understand. Can you show me how to do this on my document for me to understand clearly.
Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your mongodb version?

Comment: I checked and it say 4.0.3

Comment: You can use `$out` aggregation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a [few posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825700/convert-string-to-objectid-in-mongodb) here that hint at the solution.

```
db.students.find().forEach(function(obj) {
  obj.cust_id = ObjectId(obj.cust_id);
  db.students.save(obj);
});
```

I tested this in Atlas 4.0.6 and it worked well. I don't know, however, how well this technique will scale to a large dataset.

Just replace **students** with your own collection name.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this function turning a string into number and it worked well

```
db.students.find().forEach(obj =>{
   obj.code_number= parseInt(obj.code_number);
   db.students.save(obj);
});
```

You can also create a new collection with the results to keep the original data and check the results

```
db.students.find().forEach(obj=> {
   obj.code_number= parseInt(obj.code_number);
   db.students_new.save(obj);
});
```

Comment: The above conversion updates the value as type `double`. If you need a true `Int32`, use `NumberInt()` instead `parseInt()`.