# Import json Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So i imported a json file with

`mongoimport -d mydb -c mycollection --jsonArray < glossary.json`
the problem is that _id is stored as string in Db and not as an ObjectID

Like this

[image]

So when i try to execute findbyId/findOne({_id:id}) request i get a null as a result
I've tried the solution with `findOne({ _id: new ObjectID(id) }`  but it didn't work for me

PS: the _id in the json file is a string also 
is there is any way to convert _id from string to objectId or any other solution

Sorry if the question is duplicate

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825700/convert-string-to-objectid-in-mongodb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change datatype. Give it a try.

```
db.mycollection.find().forEach(function(element){
  element._id = ObjectId(element._id);
  db.mycollection.save(element);
})
```

Comment: Ingredient.find(function(err, ingredients) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      ingredients.forEach(element => {
        element._id = ObjectId(element._id);
        let ingredient = new Ingredient(element);
        ingredient
          .save()
          .then(ing => {})
          .catch(err => {});
      });
      res.json(ingredients);
    }
  });

Answer (score 2):

Try these command to see if it work

```
mongoimport --db dbName --collection collectionName --file fileName.json --jsonArray

mongoimport --db test --collection user --drop --file /path/user.json
```

Comment: Getting the same result

Comment: The json file that i'm using   [{
            "_id": "5ad73dc9e17caf0014c5485f",
            "product": "5ad738a4e17caf0014c53922",
            "quantity": {
                "unit": "g",
                "value": 120
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": "5ad73dc9e17caf0014c54863",
            "product": "5aa1633d7e13440014db2a0f",
            "quantity": {
                "unit": "pièce (petite)",
                "value": 1
            }
        }]

Comment: there no errors but i'm still getting the _id as a string not objectId

Comment: Try to remove _id because mongo auto generate id for you

Comment: i can't remove the _id  cz it is related to other collections

Answer (score 1):

you can open the .json file into the text Editor like `vsCode` and replace id to objectId(id) with `regex` like this:

[image]

so find : `_id: (".*")`

and replace with : `_id: ObjectId($1)`

after that import your data into the database