# NodeJs MongDB Update fails with ObjectID ref from another entity

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aws-lambda

In my NodeJS app I have this Update:

```
//here I am passing as string, but even as new ObjectID(docId) does not work.
let filter = { 'TepDocSignId' : docId, 'ClientId': clientId };
let update = { 'Solved' : true,  SolvedOn : new Date()};


const resp = await db.collection(process.env.MONGODB_WARNING_COLLECTION_NAME)
                        .updateOne({ filter }, { '$set' : update });
```

On the Node it DOES NOT work, The matchedCount and modifiedCount are allways 0

But If I do the same update on RoboMongo, it works fine!

What is going on?

Is there some kind of profiler that I can see what is doing on the Node environment?

I am using :

```
"aws-sdk": "^2.590.0",
"mongodb": "^3.5.5",
```

And the data are:

```
process.env.MONGODB_WARNING_COLLECTION_NAME = 'Warning'
docId = '5e29197dac26760002f5a7b5'
clientId = '5caf91cd800fc20002cad0fb'
```

The full code is (here I am using the IDs as ObjectID, but does not matter if I parse or pass as string it does not match anyting...)

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const ObjectID = require('mongodb').ObjectID

    let dbConnString = process.env.MONGODB_CONNECTION_STRING;
    let dbName = process.env.MONGODB_DATABASE_NAME;
    let db;

    const client = new MongoClient(dbConnString, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    });

    const createConn = async () => {
        await client.connect();
        db = client.db(dbName);
    };

async function partnerWarningOff(docId, partnerId) {

        if (!client.isConnected()) {
            try {
                await createConn();
            } catch (e) {
                throw new Error(`partnerWarningOff - OpenningConn Error: ${e}`);
            }
        }

        console.log('process.env.MONGODB_WARNING_COLLECTION_NAME', process.env.MONGODB_WARNING_COLLECTION_NAME);
        console.log('docId', docId);
        console.log('partnerId', partnerId);

        let dId = new ObjectID(docId);
        let pId = new ObjectID(partnerId);

        let filter = { 'TepDocSignId' : dId, 'PartnerId': pId };
        let update = { 'Solved' : true,  'SolvedOn' : new Date()};


        const resp = await db.collection(process.env.MONGODB_WARNING_COLLECTION_NAME)
                                .updateOne({ filter }, { '$set' : update });

        console.log('resp', resp);

        if (!resp) {
            throw new Error(`partnerWarningOff Error solving tep warning with DocId ${docId}`);
        }

    };

cheers
```

Comment: As you said matchedCount is 0, Can you print & give us `docId`,`clientId` & `process.env.MONGODB_WARNING_COLLECTION_NAME`

Comment: @whoami Just updated the question with sample data. Thanks.

Comment: if these are objectid()’s in doc you need to convert them and hit the query, can you give us ur sample doc?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string to ObjectID in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825700/convert-string-to-objectid-in-mongodb)

Comment: @whoami Nope... these IDs are ObjectID from another Entity, but if I pass as string or as  ObjectID, the match still is 0! is there some kind of profiler for Mongo? I will update the question with the full code... thanks agian.

Comment: @whoami found the problem, handler was passing ObjectId, string and I was thinking all as string, string. Thats way it was not matching anything. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

The handler was passing docId as ObjectID and the ClientId as string.

The only thing I had to do, was change the way the handler was calling the function, the correct way is

```
myfuncName(doc._id**.toString()**, doc.clientId).
```

This way I have all in string, the same way is stored in the other entity.

Answer (score 0):

**You can Follow this code..**

```
 const response = await db.collection.findOneAndUpdate({
   TepDocSignId : dId,
   PartnerId: pId 
  }, {
    $set: req.body,
  }, {
    new: true
  })
```