# Can I use dynamic variable in $match mongoose

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I want **to filtre** data using `$match` and **group it** using `$group` 
since I use dynamic variable in $match stage I got no result,

```
 let logs = await Promise.all(
      tpes.map(async (item) => {
        return await this.logModel.aggregate([
          { $match: { terminalId: item } },
          {
            $group: {
              _id: '$outcome',
              value: {
                $sum: 1,
              },
            },
          },
          {
            $project: {
              name: '$_id',
              value: 1,
              _id: 0,
            },
          },
        ]);
      }),
    );
    console.log('logs', logs);
```

**logs** here is an array contain ids from where I want to get data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript set object key by variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11508463/javascript-set-object-key-by-variable)

Comment: mongoose not js pure

Comment: You can use it, i'm assuming you just need to cast it from `string` to `ObjectId`.

Comment: Check this answer. As they say above, you need to cast to ObjectId. Either using mongoose or native driver. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825700/convert-string-to-objectid-in-mongodb